# How to optimize working with multiple ObjectFactories?

Tags: java, web-services, soap, jaxb, cxf

I'm creating a client on a quite large `wsdl` soap webservice file.

Autogeneration is done using `cxf, thus`jaxb` as usual.
Problem: there are lots of optional elements, optional classes, nested elements etc.

Thus I end up in lots of classes as follows (assume autogenerated):

```
public class MyRequest {
    JAXBElement<RequestData> data;
}

class RequestData {
    JAXBElement<String> id;
    JAXBElement<String> name;
    JAXBElement<Address> address;
}

class Address {
    JAXBElement<String> town;
    JAXBElement<String> country;
    JAXBElement<String> zip;
}
```

Now, when I want to create the `MyRequest` xml request, I have to work with multiple `new ObjectFactory()` instances, writing much boilerplate code to just set these properties.

How can this process be optimized? How do you work with many `JAXBElement` objects as ObjectFactories on large soap services?

Comment: I actually never use the generated objec factories. You might be interested in the Fluent API plugin: https://java.net/projects/jaxb2-commons/pages/Fluent-api

Comment: Well then, how to you create the `JAXBElement` variables without using the objectfactoryies?

Comment: `new JAXBElement(name, MyClass.class, myValue)`, object factories do no magic at all. There are also a few plugins which allow avoiding element reference properties in models so that you have less `JAXBElements<MyClass>` and more `MyClass` instead. The Fluent API thing also helps to reduce the trivial code.

Comment: OK so that's probably the same as ObjectFactory does, just OF is a wrapper.